# Why can't fragment save EditText state by default on orientation change?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-edittext, onsaveinstancestate

I have a fragment, which contains many EditTexts. 
And when I rotate the device the EditText goes blank. The fragment is not saving its state/value. But at the same time if I use that fragment layout for activity it stores the EditText's state. 
And yes I've given the IDs to each EditText, even to each view if that matters.

I know I can use saveInstanceState to save those values but is there any other way to do it? Cause there are almost 20 EdiText in that fragment, so should I use saveInstanceState, will it be okay to save these many variables/values in saveInstanceState?

**Update:**
I was recreating the fragment in activity on orientation change, so that was the reason, EditText was unable to save its state.
Such a silly mistake!
So now I just used saveInstanceState like following:

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        initialiseNewTaskFragment();
    }
```

And that's it. EditText is saving its state now.
Thank you JorgeGil for saving my time!

Comment: Can you post your code, it's likely that you're recreating the fragment in the activity on configuration changes. The EditText state should be saved on rotation even if you're using a fragment.

Comment: Well, this is embarrassing! 
@JorgeGil You're right, I was recreating the fragment!! I should've known this already...

Answer (score 1):

Well this is a fairly loaded question lol.
So let's start with a few points.

First, you can of course handle your own lifecycle change if you choose to NOT allow Android to reset your lifecycle on device rotate.

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```

Use that flag in your manifest if you want to retain everything and handle your own rotation changes. However, if you have a layout-land folder with different XML files, you will not want to do this.

Yes of course you can do fragment.retainInstance when nested in Activities to get it to retain values. However, retaining populated Elements with values is not something you can just natively expect it to do as the UI elements were completely redrawn, so something has to tell it to redraw it again.

So if you are going old school and you are actually still doing findViewById and myText.setText('some Stuff'). Then you may find some time savings in using a library like icepick.

https://github.com/frankiesardo/icepick

However, the BEST option by a mile is to modernize your coding practice to use DataBinding. This allows you to not care about the UI interactions anymore as the values are bound to your Fragment or Activity or Model values by default and can be done with 2-way binding. This ensures databinding always populates with the value that was last updated.

Imagine you have an object of

```
public class Student implements BaseObservable{
     String firstName;
}
```

Then in your xml you have

```
editText
    android:text="@={student.firstName}"
```

Obviously there is a little more, like you need to set your student object in the onCreate to ensure it is in the XML for using. But when the user modifies the student firstname it is retained in the model, and redrawn automatically into the Edit Text.

This is your best solution, but depends on how invested you are in the future binding techniques of Android development or if you just prefer to go status quo to get across a finish line.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Well, the problem was different, but thank you for this answer anyway. I'll consider using DataBinding though. It seems like a great way to bind UI.

Comment: How about you give a little more context, of what you would like to accomplish, and maybe someone can help. I get the feeling you just don't want to manage state, but don't want to use a library like icepick or binding, so you are hoping to simply set a flag and walk away? I gave all the options that i'm aware of, so let me know if you discover something else

Answer (score -2):

Add this in your `Activity` tag on your `AndroidManifest.xml` to avoid the recreation of the `Activity` and you won't lose the data.

```
  android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```